# Gradle task started to executes very slow

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

While I am trying to Rebuild my project, under to hood Android Studio executes a lot of different gradle tasks. Everything was good, until a week ago I noticed that the project compilation started to execute much slower, then I noticed in the "Build output" that once it came to - "Task :app:dexBuilder...", it slowed drastically and could take a few minutes to finish, however, it gets used to being much much faster. So something happened and I can't find what is the problem here.

I also noticed in Activity Monitor that Java and AS takes a lot of memory, not sure if it is actually normal, when AS takes ~7.5Gb and Java 14Gb of memory...

[image]

Are there any ideas?